# How to compare the efficiency of a trained ML model over a non learning based approach for solving the same task or problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, optimization, computational-statistics

If a certain task T is solved by a non learning based method A (lets say, an optimization based approach). We now train a machine learning model B (lets say a neural network) that solves the same task T. What are some metrics that we can use to compare their efficiency in terms of finding the solution (Assuming that the quality of the solutions is nearly same)?

Comment: Maybe this would get better answers at https://ai.stackexchange.com/ ?